# How do I reliably pull data from Meteor server collections to client collections when using an existing mongodb as MONGO_URL?

Tags: meteor

I know that there are several methods to share collections on both the client and server -- namely either in top level lib folder or publish/subscribe model -- but when I try either of these things when using mongodb running at localhost:27017 as my MONGO_URL, I am not reliably getting data on the client.  Occasionally `console.log(myCollection.findOne({}))` will return expected data in the browser but most of the time it returns undefined.

```
//Client side code
Template.controls.onCreated(function controlsOnCreated() {
  Meteor.subscribe("myEvents");
  Events = new Mongo.Collection("events");
});

//Server side code
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Events = new Mongo.Collection("events");
}

Meteor.publish('myEvents', function() {
  console.log(Events.find());
  return Events.find();
});
```

UPDATED CODE -- returns Events on server but not client:

```
//Client
Template.controls.onCreated(function controlsOnCreated() {
  this.subscribe("myEvents");
});

//Server
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("myEvents", function() {
    return Events.find();
  });
}

// /collections/events.js
Events = new Mongo.Collection("events");
```

UPDATE 2:

I am attempting to verify the publication in the browser after the page has rendered, calling `Events.findOne({})` in the Chrome dev tools console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your client:

```
Template.controls.onCreated(function controlsOnCreated() {
  Meteor.subscribe("myEvents");
  Events = new Mongo.Collection("events");
});
```

that is an odd place to define the Events variable. typically, you would put that line of code in a JS file common to both platform. e.g.

collections/events.js:

```
Events = new Mongo.Collection("events");
```

when that line runs on the server, it defines the mongo collection and creates a server-side reference to it. when it runs on the client, it creates a collection by that name in mini-mongo and creates a client-side reference to it.

you can write your onCreated like this (note "this" instead of "Meteor"):

```
Template.controls.onCreated(function() {
  this.subscribe("myEvents");
});
```

you don't say where on the client you ran your console.log with the find(). if you did it in the onCreated(), that's too early. you're seeing the effects of a race condition. typically, you might use it in a helper:

```
Template.controls.helpers({
    events() {
        return Events.find({});
    }
});
```

and display the data in the view:

```
{{#each event in events}}
    {{event.name}}
{{/each}}
```

that helper will run reactively once the data from the publish shows up.

Comment: I ran console.log in the browser dev console after the page rendered, waited about 5-10 minutes just to be sure that it would be synced.  I also at one point did have the collection declared in a common file.

Comment: if you're looking in the browser console, there needs to be an active subscription. if there isn't, then Meteor will stop publishing. you shouldn't have to wait 5-10 minutes, more like 1 second to see the results of a working publish.

Comment: After following your guidelines, Events.findOne({}) is returning data on the server side, but still undefined on the client.

Comment: can you update your question to show your most recent code?

Comment: code looks good. is that template showing on screen when you run the client-side find? have you tried writing a helper to run the find and putting the data in the view?

Comment: it's still undefined

Comment: is there data in your database? can you update your code to show how/where you're doing the find? everything else looks ok to me.

Comment: updated again - there is data in my database (findOne on the server returns a document, also verified in MongoChef) and I'm doing the find in the dev tools console on Chrome after the page has rendered -- also sorry, accidentally edited the answer instead of question

Comment: i think it's best you try to update your view code to display the data, instead of using the console. i can't tell from your comments if, when you do the find() in the console, if the template is active or not. if not, then i would not expect there to be any data. you need to take an action (and show code) that guarantees the publish is active when you do the find().

Comment: It did end up taking awhile for the data in the view to update -- the query results were massive.  Limiting it to a few results decreased the update time.